# Table imported as parquet from sqoop not working in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sqoop

I imported a table from mssql server with Sqoop 1.4.5 in parquet format. But when I try to load it from Spark shell, it throws error like :

```
scala> val df1 = sqlContext.load("/home/bipin/Customer2")
scala.collection.parallel.CompositeThrowable: Multiple exceptions thrown during a parallel computation: java.lang.NullPointerException
parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.fromParquetStatistics(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:249)
parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.fromParquetMetadata(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:543)
parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.readParquetMetadata(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:520)
parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:426)
org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.ParquetRelation2$MetadataCache$$anonfun$refresh$6.apply(newParquet.scala:298)
org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.ParquetRelation2$MetadataCache$$anonfun$refresh$6.apply(newParquet.scala:297)
scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$Map.leaf(ParArray.scala:658)
scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply$mcV$sp(Tasks.scala:54)
scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:53)
scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:53)
.
.
.
        at scala.collection.parallel.package$$anon$1.alongWith(package.scala:87)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$class.mergeThrowables(Tasks.scala:86)
        at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$Map.mergeThrowables(ParArray.scala:650)
        at scala.collection.parallel.Task$class.tryMerge(Tasks.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$Map.tryMerge(ParArray.scala:650)
        at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$class.internal(Tasks.scala:190)
        at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.internal(Tasks.scala:514)
        at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$class.compute(Tasks.scala:162)
        at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.compute(Tasks.scala:514)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:160)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

I looked at the sqoop parquet folder and it's structure is different than the one that I created on Spark. How can I make the parquet file work ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `parquetFile` instead of `load`. `load` is for data stored as DataFrame. More examples in [guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#loading-data-programmatically).

```
val df1 = sqlContext.parquetFile("/home/bipin/Customer2")
```

Comment: load has worked on parquetfiles I created in spark. So that is not the issue. I get the same error with your method.

Answer (score 1):

The Parquet version is not compatible. Spark 1.2 use parquet version 1.6. But your parquet file maybe in the version 1.7 or higher. Parquet1.6 reader cannot parse the parquet 1.7 file.

The next version of spark(maybe 1.5) will use the parquet1.7 in the future that appears in the pom.xml of the master branch.

Comment: I think next version(maybe 1.5) of spark will use the qarquet 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Spark 1.1 which comes from the parquet library, see [PARQUET-136](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-136).

> For a string or a binary column, if all values in a single column trunk are null, so do the min & max values in the column trunk statistics. However, while checking the statistics for column trunk pruning, a null check is missing, and causes NPE. Corresponding code can be found here.

This fix was brought into Spark 1.2.0, see [SPARK-3968](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3968).

Easiest fix is probably to upgrade, or if that is not possible ensure there are no columns which have only null values!

Comment: I built the spark from the github source which I took last week. Its version is 1.4.0-snapshot. So that should not be a problem. Thanks for looking up the issue. I have a feeling that it is the other side (sqoop) that is causing the problem. When looking into the Sqoop ivy.xml there is no parquet but parquet-hive-bundle. That most likely is be the problem. Sqoop uses parquet only for hive tables. Also there are efforts to directly connect to databases from spark eliminating the need of sqoop.